# Typescript 2.0 no output

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript2.0

I'm coding a project in VS 2015 update 3 and just installed Typescript 2.0.

After a lot of errors I've been on a trail and error mission to get it working again. Now I don't have any errors anymore, but I'm not getting my output file.

My source files are all in the client folder, and that folder is in the root of the project.

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "./client",
    "outFile": "./client/app.js",
    "sourceRoot": "./client"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

The project did compile when it was on version 1.8.x.

This is an example of one of my .ts files:

```
namespace app {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', [
            'ngRoute',
            'ngAnimate',
            'officeuifabric.core',
            'officeuifabric.components'
        ]);

}
```

Am I missing something?

---edit---
If I remove these lines:

```
"outDir": "./client",
"outFile": "./client/app.js",
"sourceRoot": "./client"
```

it builds without an issue. Are the parameters still supported?

--edit 2--
I've also been testing with an empty project an VS Code and the command line tsc.

My tsconfig that's working:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outFile": "app.js",
    "sourceRoot": "./client"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

However when I add Outdir, either nothing is compiled, or at the wrong location.

This does work:

```
    "outFile": "./build/app.js",
```

Comment: Is this refusing to compile, or is it just not generating the output when you have `outDir`, `outFile` and `sourceRoot`? Something I've noticed with TS and VS is that when the TS files are compiled if they are new files/directories, VS doesn't implicitly add them. You need to add them using the `Show All Files` button in the solution explored and explicitly include them in the project

Comment: It's not refusing to compile, there's just no output. No error and no files. Even when I run tsc from the command line.

Comment: Interesting...well I know the `outDir` option is still supported, I'm using it in my project right now with no issue. Perhaps try changing `outFile` to simply "app.js" since the `outDir` option already would create to ./client. But have you tried incrementally removing items to see if it's a single option preventing output?

Comment: I've tried changing the to app.js and tried removing one line at a time. It looks like the outdir param is causing the issue.

Comment: I realize this is a silly question, but I need to ask for my sake; after you compile are you checking for the files in VS Solution Explorer, or in Windows Explorer?

Comment: I'm checking in Windows Explorer. And I have the issue with VS Code. I'll update my question

Comment: Having the same issue here, on Mac (compiling through either Terminal or VS Code). Have you found anything about it?

Comment: I've posted the version that's working for me. And for the last project I moved to a gulp task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This config is working for me:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outFile": "./build/app.js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Comment: ... but not for the rest of us.

Answer (score 1):

I got this for a different reason. I had `"extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json"`, and the external tsconfig was setting `"noEmit": true`. An explicit `"noEmit": false` in my file fixed it.